# How to create a custom position grid in yootheme warp framework

Tags: grid, themes, warp

Hi friends i want to create a grid look like this picture

http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-11/40360516901990108279.png

this is the file of a grid named doubled

http://uplod.ir/tymq019i8bnx/doubled.zip.htm

tnx for your helps